# CMAKE cross compile libraries are not found

Tags: c, cmake, cross-compiling, kdevelop, angstrom-linux

I'm having strange problems with my cmake cross-compiler projects.

My own libraries are found but not the (system) libraries from my toolchain.

Previously I was using KDevelop on debian squeeze machine.
now on my new machine with debian wheezy the configuring fails. 
It does not find the system libraries like `m` or `pthread`.

On my old machine the following was working perfectly, but I do not remember that I did something special to make this work.

Here is one of my `CMakeLists.txt` files

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 2.6.36.4)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++)
include_directories(../include
  ../../../sample/include)

project(testmain)

add_executable(testmain
   some_c-source-file.c)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ../lib/arm-26/lib
  ../../../sample/lib/arm-26/lib)
find_library(LIBS_TEST NAMES akku)
find_library(LIBS_M NAMES m)
find_library(LIBS_PTHREAD NAMES pthread )
target_link_libraries(akkumain
  ${LIBS_TEST}
  ${LIBS_M}
  ${LIBS_PTHREAD})

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -Werror")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -O2 -rdynamic")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-g0 -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Werror")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -O2 -rdynamic")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-g0 -O0")
```

This is the message displayed when trying to compile using KDevelop: (to repeat myself: this was working on my old machine)

```
/home/user/testmain/build> /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug /home/user/testmain/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.3.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.3.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBS_M
    linked by target "akkumain" in directory /home/user/testmain
LIBS_PTHREAD
    linked by target "akkumain" in directory /home/user/testmain
```

So LIBS_TEST is found. But not `libm` or `libpthread`.
I tried this with different projects: All of my libraries are found, but none of the "system" libraries.

I already tried different things like

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES lib )
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a )
```

and some more things I do not remember.

**The only thing what IS WORKING is when I specify the directory manually:**

```
find_library(ASTLIBS_M NAMES m PATHS /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib)
```

After specifying this to my `CMakeLists.txt` the library is found and I can compile my project without any errors.

BUT: This is not what I want, because I have a *LOT* of projects and many libraries and I don't want to edit all my `CMakeLists.txt`... :(

**Does anybody know what made my old machine find the system-libs without specifying anything special inside my IDE/CMake files?**

Edit:
**I just noticed for one of my executables that on Linker stage it throws some errors that it cannot find some symbols from glibc - seems there is something more wrong with my debian wheezy system. - I hope I can figure it out...**

Edit:

### Maybe I should give a short summary: My code compiles well, but all libraries from my toolchain are not found, but if I add the path to the libs of my toolchain manually it compiles but fails on linker stage.

Comment: still not solved my problem. It is simply not possible to link an library from the toolchain. They ar set to NOTFOUND. -  I have no clue.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain default paths where CMake's [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) module searches.  If your system libs on your old machine happen to be located in one such place, they will be found without any additional work needing to be done.

However, as your new machine's path to these libs seems to be "/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib", you'll need to tell CMake about this.

One such way, is as you have shown (adding the path explicitly).  But in this case, the path is probably specific to just that machine - so you'd be better to only set that path when you invoke CMake on that machine.  You can add it to [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) for example:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr
```

(Note: the path in this case get "lib" appended when `find_library` is called).

Or if you only want to affect the `find_library` search paths, and not *all* `find_xxx` modules, set [`CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH)

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
```

Comment: Thanks* that is a good hint. But howto pass additional paramaters to KDevelop's build command?

Comment: I don't know kdevelop, but I imagine there's a "configure" option somewhere for each project.  It will be invoking CMake in there, and you should be able to pass additional arguments to CMake there.

Comment: Better late than never: It all ended up using set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...) inside the CMakeliste.txt

Answer (score 21):

Have you ever tried using a **toolchain file**? I also cross-compile to ARM and AVR a **LOT** and it works very well with no hassle (I also use KDevelop and it works beautifully along with CMake). The main point is specifying the path to your toolchain root filesystem through the **CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH** variable. Try putting all this in a file, which I usually name after the architecture I'm cross-compiling to (in this case I called it **arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.cmake**):

```
# the name of the target operating system
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which C and C++ compiler to use
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++) 

# here is the target environment located
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/claudio/TS-7400/rootfs) 

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search 
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
```

Note the variables **CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_xxx** variables control where `CMake` will look for binaries, libraries and header files. I usually set PROGRAM to `NEVER` so it never uses binaries from your cross-architecture root filesystem, since they will not run on your host machine anyway. For libraries and header files `BOTH` means it will search first your specified ROOT_PATH and then if it doesn't find something it will go through your host machine system dirs.

That way, whenever you want to cross-compile a project all you have to do is to create a build directory (so it doesn't mix your sources with files created during build) and then run **cmake** from there specifying the toolchain file you want to use (I'm supposing your `CMakeLists.txt` is together with your toolchain file on the same dir your sources are located - *project_sources_dir* in my example):

```
cd project_sources_dir
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.cmake ..
```

The whole point of using a toolchain file is that, if you want to compile the exact same project for your host machine, you don't have to change a single line in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Just run **cmake** without specifying the toolchain file:

```
cd project_sources_dir
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

and your project is ready for compiling native for your host machine instead. If all that isn't enough, you can look for more details here on [CMake Cross Compiling](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling)

Comment: What about a situation, when u want to install this libs to different directory (default is `/usr/local/` but you want to `/opt/cross/`). What is more your cross compiler is also in different directory than `/usr/`

Comment: Ok. I found solution:
`SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/cross/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi)`
inside `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.cmake`